# Comparison test, proving divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $a_n>0$ for all n, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges, then can I prove $\sum_ {n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ diverges by showing that $\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ = $1-\frac{1}{a_n+1}$ and then use the comparison test?

Comment: If $(a_n)$ contains infinitely many terms with $a_n > 1$, then clearly $a_n / (1 + a_n) > \frac{1}{2}$ for such $n$ and hence the second series diverges. Otherwise we may assume $a_n \leq 1$, and then we have $a_{n}/(1 + a_n) \geq \frac{1}{2} a_n$. This enables us to compare two series.

Comment: Comparison is clearer with the unmodified form.

Comment: In both cases, $a_n$ does not bound $\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ from above, right? So how can I use the comparison test in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First prove that  $\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0\iff a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ and then use [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) to show that
 $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff $\sum_ {n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ converges:$$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\frac{a_n}{1}}{\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n+1=1 \neq 0.$$

Comment: Nice answer but I think your last line should actually be the first thing you say.  If $a_n$ does not converge to $0$ then both diverge.  WLOG assume $a_n$ converges to $0$.  Then we can use the limit comparison test...

Comment: I edited. I believe now is better.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Alti: You are welcome.